# Cookie was propagated in Feign client stateless call

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, okhttp, feign

I have a REST API which calls another REST API using the Feign client. Between the two calls I have a reverse proxy which add Cookie in the Header's response.
In my next calls the Cookie is still present in the header although I only add Bearer using a Spring's Interceptor.

I don't understand how this can happen because my Feign client is a Singleton managed by Spring.

Comment: Do you have a CookieJar configured?

Comment: no I dont have any CookieJar